# Postgres how to know what are all the indexes going to be updated on update indexed json field

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Users table design is as follows,

```
id - integer
workspace_id - integer
data - json
created_at - timestamp
updated_at - timestamp
```

Stored data in json field as follows,

```
{"age": 21, "city": "London", "name": "ABC", "test_filed1": "text"}
```

I have created index like follows

```
CREATE INDEX concurrently index_user_name ON users using gist(workspace_id, (data ->> 'name') gist_trgm_ops)
```

Likewise I have few indexes for optimise the query. I want to know if I update any one field in json which is not indexed, will it update index in postgres as field is part of same json column? For instance `age` field is not indexed, will it update `index_user_name` index when I update `age` alone? Any way to run update query alone with any option to know what are indexes going to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

The index will get maintained.  There is no optimization to suppress maintenance when a value derived from the column doesn't change even though the column value itself changes.  There was [an attempt](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/4d9928ee-a9e6-15f9-9c82-5981f13ffca6%40postgrespro.ru) to add such an optimization a few years ago, but it did not succeed.

So it will not go through HOT update, and not only will that index get maintained, but so will all the other indexes on the table.

I don't know of a good way of discovering this fact without just knowing it, or digging into the internals (like with pg_waldump, or with pageinspect)